# Table of Contents with additional description of entries

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to achieve table of contents with additional description for chapters/sections (see screenshot). What way would you go to achieve this? I'm wondering if it is possible to wrap the `\chapter`, `\section` etc. commands with custom taking 2 parameters. But how to generate the ToC then?

[image: screeshot]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `\addcontentsline{toc}{<sec_unit>}{<text>}` or directly `\addtocontents{toc}{<text>}` to enter text to the `.toc` file. The only issue is to indent to text correctly.

Below some code which uses the `book` class and its internal macros.
Its adds ''info'' lines which use basically the same formatting macros as the sectioning lines (for identical indention), but avoid the '.... (page number)' part. If you really want to give `\chapter` etc. two arguments you can do something like

```
\let\Chapter\chapter \def\chapter#1#2{\Chapter{#1}\chapterinfo{#2}}
```

Here the code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
% Basically the same as for `\l@section` etc, just `\@nodottedtocline` instead of `\@dottedtcline`:
\newcommand*\l@chapterinfo{\@nodottedtocline{0}{0.0em}{1.5em}}
\newcommand*\l@sectioninfo{\@nodottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsectioninfo{\@nodottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsubsectioninfo{\@nodottedtocline{3}{7.0em}{4.1em}}
\newcommand*\l@paragraphinfo{\@nodottedtocline{4}{10em}{5em}}
\newcommand*\l@subparagraphinfo{\@nodottedtocline{5}{12em}{6em}}

% Copied from the book class macro `\@dottedtocline`. Removed the dots and page number
\def\@nodottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{\,}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor }%
     \par}%
  \fi}

\makeatother

\def\chapterinfo#1{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapterinfo}{%
    \noexpand\numberline{}#1}%
}
\def\sectioninfo#1{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{sectioninfo}{%
    \noexpand\numberline{}#1}%
}
\def\subsectioninfo#1{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsectioninfo}{%
    \noexpand\numberline{}#1}%
}
% same for subsubsection, etc. ...

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{AAA}
\chapterinfo{A very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text}

\section{aaa}
\sectioninfo{A very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text}

\subsection{1111}
\subsectioninfo{A very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image: Resulting TOC]

If this is required by more people I would be ready to make a small package out of it. I could try to also support the *koma script* or other classes.

Comment: Sharrer : Thank you as well. For long books or proceedings, I find this kind of commented toc very user-friendly.

Comment: Martin, did you ever got around into making this a package?

Comment: Inserting this into a customized book class, I get a page number on the first page ``ii``, any ideas what to look for off the cuff? Thanks.