# Adding notes to table of contents -- indentation

Tags: table-of-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Table of Contents with additional description of entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10188/table-of-contents-with-additional-description-of-entries)

I'd like to add some notes for every chapter in the table of contents.
Have a look at the following minimal compiling example for the idea.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\summary}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{\textit{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First Section}
\summary{This is the introduction. It will make the reader want to continue reading.}

\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\summary{Here we will explain in detail why this is scientificly important.}


\subsubsection{SubSubsection}
\summary{There are several elements of the argument. This is the first.}

\end{document}
```

This works great except that I would like to have the notes indented as much as the toc entry they belong to.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may add toc entries of the level of the last toc entry with the comments. But if the last entry was a section you have to remove the vertical space before the comment. So maybe:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand*{\lastlevel}{section}
\pretocmd{\section}{\def\lastlevel{section}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsection}{\def\lastlevel{subsection}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsubsection}{\def\lastlevel{subsubsection}}{}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\l@summary}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \let\@dotsep\@M
    \csname l@#2\endcsname{#1}{}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\summary}[1]{%
  \ifdefstring{\lastlevel}{section}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{-1.0em plus -1pt}}%
  }{}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\contentsline{summary}{\protect\numberline{}\normalfont\itshape
  #1}{\lastlevel}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First Section}
\summary{This is the introduction. It will make the reader want to continue reading.}

\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\summary{Here we will explain in detail why this is scientificly important.}


\subsubsection{SubSubsection}
\summary{There are several elements of the argument. This is the first.}

\end{document}
```

If you want not to indent until the text but only until the number, just remove `\protect\numberline{}`.

`\pretocmd` and `\ifdefstring` are commands of package [etoolbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox). For more information about see the package manual. If you use another class, you may have to change the `-1.0em plus -1pt`.

[image]