# Adding author to the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm currently trying to insert an author name in table of contents. My ad-hoc solution to the problem would be the following code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}


    \begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \section{Test}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\textit{Author's name}}
    \section{Test}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\textit{Author's name}}

    \end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I always get the following error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

I guess, the compiler cannot move to the next line in the toc file somehow. Does anyone know how to fix it? I'm very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `\par` after the author name.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Test}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\textit{Author's name}\par}
    \section{Test}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\textit{Author's name}\par} 
\end{document}
```

You can refer to the following question for more detailed explanation:
[missing \item with \addtocontents before \section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139620/missing-item-with-addtocontents-before-section)