# Chapter summary included in TOC and main body text

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I'd like is for a summary to appear *both* in the TOC *and* at the head of the chapter within the main-body of the work.  If possible, matching the reduced font size, *out*-dented initial line, and overall paragraph indent of the original would be a nice touch.

This is a follow-up question to the following post which I've been encouraged to post as a new question:
[Table of Contents with additional description of entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10188/table-of-contents-with-additional-description-of-entries)

I'm working off the format used in a publication of Arnold Toynbee's lectures which I'm transcribing to LaTeX.

For the moment, I've just included the descriptions at the head of the chapter tagged with \small{text}, e.g.:

```
\chapter{I Introductory}

\small{
    Division of the subject --- Advantages of combining the study of
    History and Political Economy --- The Deductive Method --- The
    Historical Method --- Importance of a discussion of Method --- Laws
    and precepts relative --- The Social Problems of the Present to be
    borne in mind in studying the history of the Past.\footnote{The
        fragment of economic history here printed under the title of
        `The Industrial Revolution', a title that Toynbee has himself
        selected for a book, of which the following pages contain some
        of the raw material, consists of notes of lectures delivered by
Toynbee in the hall of Balliol College, Oxford, between October 1881 and
Midsummer 1882.} } \\
}
```

As presented in the original publication (I'm just looking for something reasonably close, not exact):

TOC: 
http://books.google.com/books?id=rf4OAAAAQAAJ&pg=PR31#v=onepage&q&f=false

Main matter page: 
http://books.google.com/books?id=rf4OAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the sectional unit structure of the [`book in openlibrary.org`](http://archive.org/stream/cu31924102143637#page/n35/mode/2up) I noticed that you can, in fact, use `\chapter`, `\section` and (abuse) `\subsection` to achieve the desired layout.

Using a customized `\subsection` for the descriptions has the advantage that the titles will be automatically included in the ToC and that you have easy access to the optional argument (useful in case of footnotes in the description, to prevent the footnote material to appear in the ToC).

Below I give you some starting point producing almost exactly the layout of the original book; in particular the hanging indentation of the description in the body of the document and in the ToC entries was easily obtained.

The [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package was used to customize the sectional unit headings and the [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package was used to customixe the entries in the ToC:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\newcommand\periodafter[1]{#1.}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\filcenter}{}{0pt}{\periodafter{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\filcenter}{\thesection.}{\ifstrempty{#1}{-10pt}{0.5em}}{\ifstrempty{#1}{}{\periodafter{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\small}{}{0em}{\hangindent=1cm#1}

\titlecontents{chapter}
[0em]
{\addvspace{5pt}\filcenter\scshape\Large}
{\MakeUppercase}
{}
{}[\addvspace{5pt}]
\titlecontents{section}
[0em]
{\filcenter\scshape}
{\contentslabel{1em}}
{}
{}[\addvspace{5pt}]
\titlecontents{subsection}
[0em]
{\hangindent=0.5cm\small}
{}
{}
{\titlerule*[2pc]{.}\contentspage}[\addvspace{10pt}]


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Ricardo and the old political economy}
\section{}
\subsection{Division of the subject --- Advantages of combining the study of History and Political Economy --- The Deductive Method --- The
    Historical Method --- Importance of a discussion of Method --- Laws
    and precepts relative --- The Social Problems of the Present to be
    borne in mind in studying the history of the Past.}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{}
\subsection{Division of the subject --- Advantages of combining the study of History and Political Economy --- The Deductive Method --- The
    Historical Method --- Importance of a discussion of Method --- Laws
    and precepts relative --- The Social Problems of the Present to be
    borne in mind in studying the history of the Past.}
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter{The industrial revolution}
\section{Introductory}
\subsection[Division of the subject --- Advantages of combining the study of History and Political Economy --- The Deductive Method --- The
    Historical Method --- Importance of a discussion of Method --- Laws
    and precepts relative --- The Social Problems of the Present to be
    borne in mind in studying the history of the Past.]{Division of the subject --- Advantages of combining the study of History and Political Economy --- The Deductive Method --- The
    Historical Method --- Importance of a discussion of Method --- Laws
    and precepts relative --- The Social Problems of the Present to be
    borne in mind in studying the history of the Past.\footnote{The
        fragment of economic history here printed under the title of
        `The Industrial Revolution', a title that Toynbee has himself
        selected for a book, of which the following pages contain some
        of the raw material, consists of notes of lectures delivered by
Toynbee in the hall of Balliol College, Oxford, between October 1881 and
Midsummer 1882.}}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{England in 1760 --- Population}
\subsection[Division of the subject --- Advantages of combining the study of History and Political Economy --- The Deductive Method --- The
    Historical Method --- Importance of a discussion of Method --- Laws
    and precepts relative --- The Social Problems of the Present to be
    borne in mind in studying the history of the Past.]{Division of the subject --- Advantages of combining the study of History and Political Economy --- The Deductive Method --- The
    Historical Method --- Importance of a discussion of Method --- Laws
    and precepts relative --- The Social Problems of the Present to be
    borne in mind in studying the history of the Past.\footnote{The
        fragment of economic history here printed under the title of
        `The Industrial Revolution', a title that Toynbee has himself
        selected for a book, of which the following pages contain some
        of the raw material, consists of notes of lectures delivered by
Toynbee in the hall of Balliol College, Oxford, between October 1881 and
Midsummer 1882.}}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

An image of the ToC:

[image]

An image of the first page of chapter two:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look on the accepted answer of similar question and modify the code in the answer in this way:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10189/3324

```
...etc...
\def\chapterinfo#1{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapterinfo}{%
    \noexpand\numberline{}#1}%
    { \small \it #1 }
}
\def\sectioninfo#1{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{sectioninfo}{%
    \noexpand\numberline{}#1}%
    { \small \it #1 }
}
...etc...
```