# Formatting problem with table of contents LaTeX

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to obtain a table of contents like this one:

[image: Table of contents]

But I haven't found yet how to instruct LaTeX to format a table of contents like this. 
I have also tried a different approach giving up the table of contents and using instead an ordinary table. But also with tables I wasn't able to reproduce this kind of index.

**UPDATE**: I've tried to use the suggestions provided and I put them together into:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\l@chapterinfo{\@nodottedtocline{0}{0.0em}{1.5em}}

\def\@nodottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{\,}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor }%
     \par}%
  \fi}

\makeatother

\def\chapterinfo#1{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapterinfo}{%
    \noexpand\numberline{}#1}%

}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First conference}
\chapterinfo{\textit{\textbf{Some place, 12 may 2014}}}
\chapterinfo{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}
But I haven't found yet how to instruct LaTex to format a table of contents ike this. I have also tried a different approach giving up the table of contents and using instead an ordinary table. 

\chapter{Second conference}
\chapterinfo{\textit{\textbf{Some place, 22 may 2014}}}
\chapterinfo{Pellentesque pellentesque hendrerit urna, et commodo metus rhoncus ut. Praesent eget magna nec leo rhoncus congue nec non leo.}
But I haven't found yet how to instruct LaTex to format a table of contents like this. I have also tried a different approach giving up the table of contents and using instead an ordinary table. But also with tables I wasn't able to reproduce this kind of index.

\end{document}
```

But:

- How do I suppress the number before the title of the conference?
- How do I put "*Some place*" in the right side?
- How do I suppress "Chapter x" in the following pages?

I wasn't able to find how to use this tip:

```
\let\Chapter\chapter \def\chapter#1#2{\Chapter{#1}\chapterinfo{#2}}
```

Where can I find some documentation about it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [Table of Contents with additional description of entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10188/5764) covers the descriptors-per-sectional-unit part...

Comment: I thought you wanted the number before the conference? (It is there in the example you posted.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution.  The strategy is to define a custom command `\conference` that allows you to include the location info, description, etc.  This then adds some commands `\infoa` and `\infob` in the `.toc` file so that it is available when the contents line is typeset.

Finally, the conference is typeset as a chapter (but this could be a section if you prefer) without or with a star (to suppress the number as you mention).  The format of the contents page is controlled with the [titletoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package, with the numbers and pages hanging out in the margins with `\llap` and `\rlap`.  (The choice of fonts etc. needs to be fixed, but I sort of matched your example.)

If you don't like the formatting of the chapters, then you can use the [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package to customize these.

I have used a few other useful packages like [etoolbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) for delaying expansion and [suffix](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/suffix) for defining starred commands.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}           % For custom toc formatting
%\usepackage{titlesec}          % If you want control of the chapter look
\usepackage{etoolbox}           % For \csuse
\usepackage{suffix}             % For defining starred commands

%% These are just for convenience: they could be used directly in the
%% \titlecontents command.
\def\confloc{\textit{\infoa}}                % Formatting of location
\def\confinfo{\normalsize\textsf{\infob}}    % Formatting of info
\def\confpage{Pag.~\thecontentspage}         % Formatting of page

\titlecontents{chapter}                      % Use section if you prefer
  [0pt]
  {\large}                                   % Overall font
  {\llap{\thecontentslabel.\hspace{0.5em}}}  % Numbered label before title
  {}                                         % Unnumbered label
  {\hfill\confloc%                           % After label (loc and page)
   \rlap{\hspace{1em}\confpage}}
  [\vspace{\baselineskip}                    % Below the entry.
   \confinfo\csuse{par}                      % Can't use \par directly
   \vspace{\baselineskip}]

%% Usage: \conference[location and date]{Title}{Description}
%%        \conference*[location and date]{Title}{Description}
\newcommand{\conference}[3][]{               % Numbered version
  \addtocontents{toc}{
    \csdef{infoa}{#1}
    \csdef{infob}{#3}
  }
  \chapter{#2}                              % Could use sections etc. here
}

% Starred version
\WithSuffix\newcommand{\conference}*[3][]{  % Unnumbered starred version
    \addtocontents{toc}{
    \csdef{infoa}{#1}
    \csdef{infob}{#3}
  }
  \chapter*{#2}                             % Could use sections etc. here
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}
}

% Change the name from Chapter to Conference
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Conference}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\conference[Some place, 12 may 2014]%
           {First conference}%
           {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}%
But I haven't found yet how to instruct LaTex to format a table of contents
like this. I have also tried a different approach giving up the table of
contents and using instead an ordinary table.

\conference*[Some place, 22 may 2014]%
            {Second conference}%
            {Pellentesque pellentesque hendrerit urna, et commodo metus
             rhoncus ut. Praesent eget magna nec leo rhoncus congue nec non
             leo.}%
But I haven't found yet how to instruct LaTex to format a table of contents
like this. I have also tried a different approach giving up the table of
contents and using instead an ordinary table. But also with tables I wasn't
able to reproduce this kind of index.

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image: Sample ToC table from code]

The first conference has a number and the `\chaptername` which I have changed to `Conference`:

[image: First chapter (numbered)]

The second conference has no number of `Chapter` label since it is typeset as an unnumbered chapter with the `\chapter*` command.

[image: Second chapter (no number)]

## References

- [Defining starred versions of commands (* macro)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4386)
- [Table of Contents with additional description of entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10188)