# Reference other chapters by chapter number without \label

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, cross-referencing, chapters

In short, I need to recode the table of contents, as I intend to include a short intro or summary as to what the chapter is about and all. Of course, if a package is already constructed for this purpose, that would be great too.

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \Nameref{<chapter-number>} \hfill \Pageref{<chapter-number>}
        This chapter is about blah.
\end{enumerate}
```

However, I don't want to constantly keep labeling every chapter of the book to go back and update this over and over.

Is there any code for `\Nameref` and `\Pageref` commands above (which function similar to `\nameref` and `\pageref` but reference the chapter number directly)?

Comment: I think you want something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10189/1952

Comment: Depends on the class you use (you give no information), I'd simply add the intro directly into the toc from right after the appropriate `\chapter` cmd in your doc. For example, the memoir class has build in features to do this. If you're using another class, the memoir code can easily be copied.

Comment: @daleif I was using a book class, but I think something like that could be changed. First time I heard of memoir.

Comment: Look up `\chaptertocprecis` in the manual. It something presis. Memoir should be a drop in replacement for book, already contains the code from a lot of packages

Answer (score 2):

A version with automatic label generation and a `helpchapter` associated counter. The `\label` is injected after `\refstepcounter{chapter}` and is prefixed with `helpchapter:`

The macro `\DisplayEnumTocLine{Foo}` uses `enumi` as counter and retracts the name and page reference as `\nameref{helpchapter:\number\value{enumi}}` etc. The content of the mandatory argument is displayed as description text.

The starred version of `\DisplayEnumTocLine` does not generate hyperlinks for the name and page references, the example shows usages of both versions.

(Note: The `xassoccnt` package is not really necessary here, but it simplifies the automatic stepping of `helpchapter` here).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\newcounter{helpchapter}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{chapter}{helpchapter}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
}{%
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \label{helpchapter:\number\value{helpchapter}}%
}{}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\DisplayEnumTocLine}{sO{helpchapter:}+m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \nameref*{#2\number\value{enumi}} \hfill  \pageref*{#2\number\value{enumi}}% 
  }{%
    \nameref{#2\number\value{enumi}} \hfill  \pageref{#2\number\value{enumi}}% 
  }%

  #3%
}


\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{blindtext}



\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \DisplayEnumTocLine{A foo chapter}
\item \DisplayEnumTocLine*{\blindtext} 
\end{enumerate}

\chapter{Foo chapter}

\chapter{Other chapter}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add your additional information to the ToC:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand*{\addchapterinfo}[1]{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapterinfo}{#1}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\l@chapterinfo}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \leftskip 1.5em% same as \l@chapter uses
    \noindent #1\par
  \endgroup
  \addvspace{.5\baselineskip}% add additional vertical space  
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\addchapterinfo{This is additional text for the chapter entry}
\lipsum

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\addchapterinfo{\blindtext}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First Section in Second Chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: ToC with additional chapter info and section]

If you don't like the section entries in the ToC, use `\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}`. This will result in:

[image: ToC with additional chapter info but without sections]